# How to use 3rd party libraries which are incompatible with buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I am using 3rd party library on a new android project but, it shows me the error below but, if I remove the usage of this library then my project runs fine. 
The error image 
[android sdk 25 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jy3t.png)

The library I want to use is `compile 'com.github.pro100svitlo:lockpattern:0.9.3'`

Is there any way I can get rid of this error and work with this library?

Comment: this is the  actual error `manifest merger failed with multiple errors` expand it and see in detail

Comment: Already done but no useful info

Comment: post detail error log

Comment: shows nothing in error log. This happened after updating studio to 2.3

Comment: Use gradle on the command-line with debug and/or stacktrace parameter to get an detailed error message.